# How to get the Hometown and Gender of Users from Facebook

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the hometown and gender of users who comment on a specific Page Post, using the facebook graph API or any other?

More precisely, when I do extract comments on a Page Post with Graph API, it shows me all the IDs of Users who had posted comments. But I need also hometown where they live in order to assign the results of Sentiment Analysis to each city.

```
GET /v2.6/{PageID_PostID}/comments?fields=from&limit=150
```

[image: Graph API]

so far as I know Twitter API has such a possibility (using Python’s Tweepy library), but is it possible to extract such a data from Facebook?

I appreciate any help you might have.

Vahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s not possible, you even need an extra permission to authorize a user in order to get his hometown, and you can´t get the gender without authorization either.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with extra permission? You mean as a developer you can get an extra permission from Facebook to have access to more/other data?

Comment: there is a permission called "user_hometown", each user has to authorize that permission in your app in order to get the hometown. take a look at the docs, there is a "scope" parameter in the login process for asking additional permissions.

Comment: Ah, ok, but then this is the case when you build an app for FB users, right? What if I just want to make some post statistics?

Comment: you should read the docs, that´s a quite broad question and not really related to this thread. in general, you would use the insights api for post statistics. take a look at that one. also, make sure you know what access tokens there are, and how to use them: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/